# Adding a TextInput object to a MovieClip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have a screen, in which I want to add a TextInput object. This so the player can enter his or her name for the highscore.

How can I do this? I've read about adding the TextInput using the `T` tool and drag it in. But how can I access it's value or event on enter-key into my HighscoreScreen.as code?

Can't I add a TextInput programatically? `TextInput` isn't known in Flash, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, indeed, just use the `T` tool to draw an input text field. Make sure you set the field type to `Input Text` and to assign an instance name to it (for example `txtName`). Then in your code, you can access the field like so:

```
import flash.text.*;
import flash.display.*;
...

// Code class for the score screen.
public class ScoreScreen
{
    private var m_mcScreen:MovieClip = null;
    private var m_txtName:TextField = null;
    ...

    public function ScoreScreen ( mcScreen:MovieClip )
    {
        m_mcScreen = mcScreen;

        InitName ();
    }

    public function InitName ():void
    {
        // This assumes that m_mcScreen has a direct child named 'txtName'
        // If the text field is more deeply nested, you need to navigate
        // through the entire hierarchy of display objects until you
        // reach the text field.
        m_txtName = mcScreen.getChildByName ( "txtName" ) as TextField;
        m_txtName.text = "Default text";
    }
}
```

I used this code in my Flash games - my setup is such that I have a dedicated movie clip for each major screen of the game and each has a class that implements the logic for that entire screen. (I have no code at all in the .fla file - this helps a lot with working in a team.)

Beware, I haven't actually compiled this code. There may be missing imports or minor bugs.